# Styling a WPF Combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, styles

That is my Combobox:

```
<ComboBox Width="320" Height="35" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

[image]

1. how can I remove the rounded corners?
2. How can I set the Background to a simple white?

is it possible to solve this with the style attribute??

Comment: Yes, definitely. See [ComboBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) for what to do.

Comment: Note you will need to re-template as in the article, I don't think it's possible to do what you want with just the style attribute.